# XAML Visibility Binding not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have bound Visiblity of two buttons in my xaml code i am trying to use a play / pause button, what i want to do is hide the play button after it is clicked and show the pause button, not entirely sure if this is the best way to do it but hey, if it works we're good!

here:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid Width="50" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Button x:Name="PlayButton" Style="{DynamicResource MetroCircleButtonStyle}" Visibility="{Binding PlayButtonVisibility}"
                    Width="50" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="OnPlayButtonClicked"
                    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:MainWindow}">
                <Rectangle Width="20"
                           Height="20">
                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                        <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill"
                                     Visual="{StaticResource appbar_control_play}" />
                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                </Rectangle>
            </Button>

            <Button x:Name="PauseButton" Style="{DynamicResource MetroCircleButtonStyle}" Visibility="{Binding PauseButtonVisibility}"
                    Width="50" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="OnPauseButtonClicked"
                    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:MainWindow}">
                <Rectangle Width="20"
                           Height="20">
                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                        <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill"
                                     Visual="{StaticResource appbar_control_pause}" />
                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                </Rectangle>
            </Button>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

C# code here:

```
  private Visibility _playButtonVisiblity;
    private Visibility _pauseButtonVisiblity = Visibility.Hidden;

    public Visibility PlayButtonVisibility
    {
        get
        {
            return _playButtonVisiblity;
        }
        set { _playButtonVisiblity = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("playButton");
        }
    }

    public Visibility PauseButtonVisibility
    {
        get
        {
            return _pauseButtonVisiblity;
        }
        set
        {
            _pauseButtonVisiblity = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("pauseButton");
        }
    }
```

but for some reason or another every single time i try to change visibility using code, it doesn't take affect, no idea as to why this would be considering everything so far looks correct.

Comment: in addition to the answers you already got, i just want to point oit, that you might also get the behaviour you are looking for with a styled ToggleButton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call you'r notify wrong.

```
public Visibility PauseButtonVisibility
{
    get
    {
        return _pauseButtonVisiblity;
    }
    set
    {
        _pauseButtonVisiblity = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("PauseButtonVisibility"); // <---- This is what you want.
    }
}
```

Comment: This is correct.
Use this VM base class and then you don't need to pass the name, as long as you are calling PropertyChanged within the property you want to notify. Saves having to deal with these silly typos.
https://pastebin.com/aLMXRN50

Comment: I would also suggest to not use *Visibility* type in your view model. From my point of view it is better to have boolean property that defines if element should be available or not and in view layer you have to also use *BooleanToVisibilityConverter*.

Comment: @Joagwa Yes, he don't need to pass anyting if he's using CallerMemberName attribute in his Notify implementation. But if he'll call it wrong, it won't work. Or maybe I missunderstand you :d

Comment: i am using the correct property name now, still no change in visibility in any aspect.

Comment: @rraszewski instead of BooleanToVisibilityConverter, i would just did this with dataTrigger in Xaml. I don't like too much helper class if not needed :d

Comment: @CoreyJames Do you have any 'System.Data.Error Binding' in your output in VisualStudio?

Comment: @sTrenat yes here 'System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'PlayButtonVisibility' property not found on 'object' ''Project' (HashCode=44888241)'. BindingExpression:Path=PlayButtonVisibility; DataItem='Project' (HashCode=44888241); target element is 'Button' (Name='PlayButton'); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')
'

Comment: @CoreyJames, where do you have your 'PlayButtonVisibility'? In Project class?

Comment: Well, thath means, that your DataContext does not have any PlayButtonVisibility Property, so you have to make sure the Property is defined in the object you are using as the DataContext on the Button

Comment: what if i can't define the property inside the Project class, considering the Project class is in fact from an API ?

Comment: @CoreyJames is your Project class defined as partial?

Comment: Yes  public partial class Project : Entity { }

Comment: @CoreyJames Could you just derive from your Project class, and bind to you'r derived class instead of base class? Like 
  public class ProjectExtended: Project
        {
            private Visibility _playButtonVisiblity; 
            ... 
        }

Comment: @sTrenat had no idea what partial was until now, so yes this should work now i think, let me get back to you when i've tried it.

Comment: @sTrenat it's all working how it should now, feel free to post an answer the problem was exactly as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the correct property name in the notify event

`NotifyPropertyChanged("PlayButtonVisiblity");`

Comment: Still nothing? :/

Comment: Then you should check if your ViewModel is set as DataContext.

Comment: https://hastebin.com/nidehitopu.cs here is my code, not sure what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You are binding Visibility property of a Button to a property in your ViewModel, but in the setter, you are notifying a View that private field value has changed.

You have to notify about property change, since that's just what the View can access:

```
NotifyPropertyChanged("PauseButton");
```

Also binding to a Visibility enum in ViewModel is not the best practice, because this enum is strictly View related. I'd recommend you to simply bind to a bool property and use converter class to convert your value from Visibility enum to boolean value.

Comment: Already been made aware of this, and the issue is fixed, thanks for you answer anyway.